# Oracle: importing data pump dump without knowledge dump file content

Tags: import, oracle10g, impdp

Old approach for exporting/importing whole schema:

```
 exp user/pwdp@server FILE=export.dmp OWNER=user ROWS=Y
 imp newuser/pwd@server FULL=Y FILE=export.dmp
```

New approach:

```
 expdp user/pwdp@server DUMPFILE=export.dp DIRECTORY=exportfolder
```

However had a problem with importing:

```
 impdp newuser/pwdp@server DUMPFILE=export.dp DIRECTORY=exportfolder
```

will not import anything:

```
Connected to: Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
ORA-31655: no data or metadata objects selected for job
ORA-39154: Objects from foreign schemas have been removed from import
Master table "NEWUSER"."SYS_IMPORT_FULL_01" successfully loaded/unloaded
Starting "NEWUSER"."SYS_IMPORT_FULL_01":  newuser/********@server
DUMPFILE=export.dp DIRECTORY=exportfolder
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE_DATA
Job "NEWUSER"."SYS_IMPORT_FULL_01" successfully completed at 19:13:04
```

Adding schemas option will not help (result is same, oracle does not allow import non-owned objects):

```
impdp newuser/pwdp@server DUMPFILE=export.dp DIRECTORY=exportfolder schemas=user
```

And only one working approach which I found:

```
impdp newuser/pwdp@server DUMPFILE=export.dp DIRECTORY=exportfolder remap_schema=newuser:user
```

So the question is how to import schema data pump dump without knowledge which schema was exported?

(Of course I can look to first 512 bytes of export file and find string like "USER"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_01"), but may be exists another approach?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, technically you are not using the full=y correctly:

```
imp newuser/pwd@server FULL=Y FILE=export.dmp
```

You should rather do:

```
imp newuser/pwd@server touser=newuser fromuser=user FILE=export.dmp
```

Which is similar to impdp remap_schema command.

However, I do understand that what you are trying to do is import a schema from one user to the other without knowing the source user before hand. I just had to mention this because if you don't know the source user, then it can be easily assumed you don't know the content of the datafile; and if you don't know the content of the datafile, you could be importing a lot more users and data than you think you ought to by issuing a full=y.

Point: A full=y import means to import every user and their associated content; regardless of the user you are using to log into the database and start the import.

Having said my disclaimer, impdp has the exact same functionality in respect to a full import - just use full=y

```
impdp newuser/pwdp@server DUMPFILE=export.dp DIRECTORY=exportfolder full=y
```

**UPDATE**

```
this will works in newuser have privilege: IMP_FULL_DATABASE

execution `grant IMP_FULL_DATABASE to newuser` solved it.
```

References:
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/dp_import.htm#sthref301

Comment: thanks for suggestion, however full=y does not help anyway, error will be same: ORA-39154: Objects from foreign schemas have been removed from import, so actually import done :). But its pointless because its does not load any objects from the dump, because its different schema.

Comment: @Michael Pakhanstov - That's right, a full=y will tell the import to import data into the database for the users that are in the import. If new_user does not have data in the import, which in your example it doesn't, then you will not see any data or objects in new_user; that's where remap_schema comes into play. ORA-39154 indicates you do not have the privilege to import other users data - which is what you are doing with full=y for both imp and impdp.